# Subversion see who is currently working on a file?

Tags: version-control, visualsvn-server

I'm using VisualSVN as my Subversion server. How can I see who is currently working on a file or files? And also how can I see who has checked out a file and when? I am open to using a different program but it needs to be compatible with Windows. My server is on Windows Server 2012 R2. My team works in Windows 7 (in the future will be upgrading to Windows 10). The VisualSVN has a web interface but it just shows who has checked-IN a file.

Comment: I know of no way to do such a thing.  Nor should there be.  That sounds like the stuff that Microsoft's Visual Source Safe used to do.

Comment: SVN is not tracking work in progress, only commits. So you know who was on a file, but not who is actually working on a file. You would need to track the development environment, I guess. I do not know such a feature.